# Is there a lens system that captures paraxial parallel light and turn it to a certain direction?

Tags: optics, lenses

To turn arbitrary parallel light into a designated direction, one can make use of a flat mirror and an electric motor that turns it to a desired direction. I would like to know if this can be simplified one step further. Is it possible to turn parallel light whose direction is in a cone (eg. no more than 30 degrees off axis) into a **almost** parallel light bundle in a certain direction?

The whole thing is designed for illumination with sunlight so precision doesn’t matter a lot.

I start to think of adding something to a mirror with the shape of a concave hemisphere, and got stuck right here.

---

EDIT: The comment says that it is still unclear what I am asking about, so here is a diagram

[image: diagram]

Since sun rises and sets, and change its altitude in seasons, in certain period of a day, it is from one of the arrows above. The light comes out through the dashed line and is used for illumination for something in that direction (eg. a traditional biological microscope).

I understand how to turn the light if I got an electric motor that spins a flat mirror, but can this process be done using only static lens system?

Comment: Can you  clarify "parallel light whose direction is in a cone"?    That seems  unlikely.... ;-)

Comment: @garyp I meant that angle between the direction of the parallel light and a given direction is less than a given number, like 30 degrees. (So the directions of them resembles a cone, although this analogy seems poor)

Comment: A lens changes converging/diverging rays into parallel rays.

Comment: @sammygerbil Sorry, but I didn’t really get it. Are you saying that it is impossible, or the question is too elementary and I did miss some trivial fact? Or something else?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Perhaps if you provide a diagram. The solution does look obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Google images for Multi Mirror Telescope and you will see lots of pictures of arrays of mirrors doing just that.

Telescope mirrors are not that much different from what you seem to have in mind. They are very precise and expensive because they direct light as exactly as possible to the same place, and they must not introduce distortions. But other than that, they are the same. That said, there is no such thing as a cheap large concave mirror.

The focus where the light meets is usually a long distance from the mirror. That means the mirrors are fairly flat. For a telescope, light sources are very dim stars seen at night. When you bring that light to a focus, you still have a very dim light.

You want to use this with sunlight. That can be dangerous, just like a giant magnifying glass bringing light to a focus. Fortunately, you would not work near the focus. If you want illumination, you can get that with a flat mirror. You would light up a spot about the same size and shape as the mirror. With a slightly concave mirror, light would follow a converging cone. You would light up a smaller spot, but the spot would be brighter. Just make sure you choose a mirror so the spot doesn't get too small and bright, or you can blind people or start fires.

Answer (score 0):

Any parabolic reflector with the addition of fiber conductor at the focal point?

Comment: Please add more detail to explain your answer. How will the parabolic reflector address the changing direction of the incoming light? How will the arrangement meet the requirements for the Numerical Aperture of the fibre? Possibly you are intending to make a comment/suggestion instead of provide a comprehensive answer.